# Persistir JSON criando Objetos da Lista

Tags: api, jpa, spring-boot

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou com uma dúvida, tento persistir um JSON pela API:

```
{
 ...
        "Analise": [{
            "nProcAnalitic": "SR-000446/2015",
            ...
        }]
...
}
```

E o serviço me responde 200:

```
...
  "Analise": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "lotEntity": null,
      "nProcAnalitic": "SR-000446/2015"
...
```

Porem sem criar o objeto da listagem, somente o objeto pai.

Mapeamento:

@JsonProperty("Analise")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lotEntity")
private List analysis;

...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_lot")
private LotEntity lotEntity;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que só falta você especificar a propriedade cascade=ALL na annotation oneToMany, assim o JPA vai persistir/alterar/excluir os objetos filhos em cascata.

Comment: Realmente, faltava o cascade.ALL, porem o objeto de referencia do pai dentro da listagem não gravou o id, ficando null... 

...
  "Analise": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "lotEntity": null,

Comment: Você deve setar a entidade pai na entidade filha manualmente. Eu aconselho você a usar a anotação @postPersist em um método na classe pai, assim que o JPA inserir a entidade pai, e antes de inserir os filhos, ele vai invocar esse método e você pode setar o objeto pai (this) no objeto filho (analise).

Comment: Opa, deu certo:     @PostPersist
    public void setObject() {
        this.analysis.forEach(a -> a.setLotEntity(this));
    } Obrigado